# Switch between tabs WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I am using WinEdt to write and compile Latex files. Often I do have several .tex files open and I would like to switch between tabs. 
E.g. On Google Chrome you can use CTRL+PgUp or CTRL+PgDown to havigate through tabs.

However, that does not work on WinEdt. Does anyone knows whether there is a shortcut or whether is it possible to setup one?

Thank you!

Comment: Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+shift+Tab

Comment: Thanks, that works! 
Is there anyway do redefine that shortcut?

Comment: Ctrl+Comma works too. You find the MDI-entries in the "Window" menu and you can adapt the shortcuts in menu.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` switches between "MDI"-windows (I never understood the order it uses), `Ctrl+Comma` and `Ctrl+Shift+Comma` between windows. You can adapt the shortcuts in `menu.ini`.

Comment: >> I never understood the order it uses.